# resetting reactive form triggers all required validators in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular6

I am new to angular 6 ,Here I am trying to reset the form after submitting the data.

Everything works fine but when I reset the form after successful data submit to database it triggers all the required validators in the form.

I tried many ways to solve this but I couldn't solve it .

**Here after each form submission I want to reset the form and all the validators before enter the data in form fields for another submission.**

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="newMemberForm" (submit)="CreateMember(newMemberForm.value)" novalidate>
....
....
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
            this.newMemberForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  M_Number: ['', [Validators.required]],
                  F_Number: ['', [Validators.required]],
                  M_Name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
                  M_Status: ['', [Validators.required]],
                  M_Dob: ['', [Validators.required]],
                  M_Sex: ['', [Validators.required]],

                });

       CreateMember(memberForm) { 
        this.dmlService.CreateNewMember(memberForm).subscribe(data => {
              if (data[0]['RESPONSE'] == 'TRUE') 
         {
         this.newMemberForm.reset();
        }
       });
}
```

Here I have reset the form it triggers the required validatord.If I clears all the validators inside the above function ,When I enter another form data the validations are not working.

Here I want to reset all the validator and form after each form submission and I want to submit next set of form data .

can anyone help me to solve this .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to reset as below:

In your html:

```
<form [formGroup]="newMemberForm" #formDirective="ngForm"  
(submit)="CreateMember(newMemberForm.value,formDirective)" novalidate>
```

In .ts:

```
CreateMember(value,formDirective:FormGroupDirective){
 ...
 formDirective.resetForm();
 this.myForm.reset();
}
```

Material checks the validity of `FormGroupDirective` and not of `FormGroup` hence resetting `FormGroup` does not reset `FormGroupDirective`.

Issue reported here too: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9347

Answer (score 0):

Thats great solution but, reactive forms have their own feature to do so.

You can remove validations on specific formGroup/formcontrol by using clearValidators() for reactive forms.

```
this.formGroup.clearValidators() or      
 this.formGroup.controls.controlName.clearValidators()
```

After this, you have to update form control with the removed validator

```
this.formGroup.controls.controlName.updateValueAndValidity()
```

This helped me to resolve same issue, hope it helps you too

Comment: Unfortunately, when clearing validators, we need to add them again in order for them to work for subsequent inputs. By simply doing `controlName.clearValidators()` and `controlName.updateValueAndValidity()` the validators will be removed (at least since Angular 13).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518781/834493) and [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4190#issuecomment-311488176), with details in the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown):

The problem is that `FormGroup::reset()` does not clear the submitted state which also triggers the validators with some ErrorStateMatchers.
The submitted state is tracked by a `FormGroupDirective` object. Use `FormGroupDirective::resetForm()` to clear it.
If you're using Angular Material, the default ErrorStateMatcher will check `form.submitted` in addition to `control.invalid` and `control.touched`.
So you have 2 options: get a reference to the directive and call `resetForm()`, or declare a custom `ErrorStateMatcher` that doesn't check for submitted state and use it on your inputs as shown in the docs.

Option 1:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: '...'
})
export class MyCustomComponent {

  @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) formGroupRef: FormGroupDirective | undefined;  // <<----

  myInputFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private myService: MyService) {
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      myInput: this.myInputFormControl
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.myFormGroup.valid) {
      let myData: MyData = {
        myInput: this.myInputFormControl.value;
      }

      // submit form to server
      this.myservice.submitData(myData).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          console.log('Data submitted successfully! Response: ', response);
          this.formGroupRef?.resetForm();               // <<----
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log("Errors while submitting data: ", err);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="myInputFormControl">
    <mat-error *ngIf="myInputFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Value is required
    </mat-error>
</form>
```

Option 2, custom ErrorStateMatcher:

```
/** Error when invalid control is touched */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && control.touched);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: '...'
})
export class MyCustomComponent {

  myInputFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  myMatcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private myService: MyService) {
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      myInput: this.myInputFormControl
    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    // submit form to server
    this.myFormGroup.reset();
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]='myFormGroup' (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="myInputFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="myMatcher">
    <mat-error *ngIf="myInputFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Value is required
    </mat-error>
</form>
```