# Angular 6 Material form reset makes Validation error appear

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material-6

When i first load the page, the form appears like this

[image]

But after i successfully create an announcement, i reset the page with `this.announcementCreateForm.reset()` code and it resets the below way

[image]

I call the below method `buildAnnouncementForm()` during `ngOnInit()`

```
 private buildAnnouncementForm() {
    this.announcementCreateForm = this.fb.group({
      announcementTitle: ['', [Validators.required]],
      announcementText: '',
      announcementFor: ['', [Validators.required]],
      announcementType: ['', [Validators.required]],
      announcementFromDate: [this.announcementFromDate, Validators.required],
      announcementToDate: [this.announcementToDate, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

I call the `reset` method after `success`

```
resetAnnouncementPage() {
    if (this.announcementCreateForm.valid) {
      console.log("Reset...");
      this.announcementCreateForm.reset();
      this.announcementCreateForm.markAsPristine();
      //this.announcementCreateForm.markAsUntouched();
    }
  }
```

My reset, wants me to bring the form like it looks during loading.. how to do it ?

Comment: Check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52818828/4868839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed these steps and achieved it

Added formDirective to the form and passed it to my `onSubmit` method

```
 <form #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formDirective)" [formGroup]="announcementCreateForm">
```

passed the `formDirective` argument to my `reset` method and `reset` the `formDirective` first and then i did `reset` the `form`

```
resetAnnouncementPage(formDirective:FormGroupDirective) {
    if (this.announcementCreateForm.valid) {
      formDirective.resetForm();
      this.announcementCreateForm.reset();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It would be really great if I could do something like you explained in this answer. I tried implementing your idea. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arwd3q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts It doesn't work for this scenario, What do I miss here?

Comment: I guess you need to add `#formDirective="ngForm"` in your form and then pass `formDirective` in to your `method`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to revert the form in its initial state, then store that state in a value and use it to set the form value when you want to reset the form,
Don't do `form.reset()`, it will remove even the empty strings from the from controls.

```
initialFormValue = {
    announcementTitle: '',
    announcementText: '',
    announcementFor: '',
    announcementType: '',
    announcementFromDate: this.announcementFromDate,
    announcementToDate: this.announcementToDate
}

resetAnnouncementPage() {
    if (this.announcementCreateForm.valid) {
      console.log("Reset...");
      this.announcementCreateForm.setValue(this.initialFormValue);
      this.announcementCreateForm.markAsPristine();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can also pass the value to reset with while doing a form `reset()`.

```
private _initialValue

private buildAnnouncementForm() {

    this.announcementCreateForm = this.fb.group({
      announcementTitle: ['', [Validators.required]],
      announcementText: '',
      announcementFor: ['', [Validators.required]],
      announcementType: ['', [Validators.required]],
      announcementFromDate: [this.announcementFromDate, Validators.required],
      announcementToDate: [this.announcementToDate, Validators.required]
    });

    this._initialValue = this.announcementCreateForm.value

}

resetAnnouncementPage() {

    if (this.announcementCreateForm.valid) {
      this.announcementCreateForm.reset(this._initialValue);
    }

}
```